# A lightweight Linux version for web development?

Tags: linux, operating-system, virtual-machine

I am fairly of familiar with Ubuntu and I have used it a lot in the past for programming purposes, but right now I would like to try something different. Instead of doing a dual boot on my computer, I am going to do my PHP development in a Virtual Machine, probably using VMWare or whatever.

The problem is, that with only 4GB of RAM, it seems like recent versions of Ubuntu are a bit too heavy to run really smoothly on this computer. So instead, I am searching for a Linux system that can easily run with only 1/2 or 1 GB of RAM assigned to it.

What would you suggest for this?

I'm not really sure if it makes a difference, but here's a list of the things I'll really need to be using in it:

```
apache2 
php5 
php5-memcache 
php5-sqlite 
memcached 
postgresql 
php5-pgsql 
phppgadmin
```

I understand that this is not really the typical kind of questions you find on stackoverflow, but I'm very certain that it may be useful to somebody someday.

Comment: Most Linux distros will run happily in 256M without X11. 512M is *very* generous for development. Try Ubuntu Server if Ubuntu is your thing.

Comment: If I were to install a GUI (say, Gnome) on Ubuntu Server, how much more RAM would it need?

Comment: No flying idea. I would not use GUI on a server, *or* on a VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). It will share your current directory with the guest. So you use your native editing tools and your native browser to test things. That way the VM stays small with no GUI.

Comment: Sorry for necro-ing this thread, but how long does it take for vagrant to download all the packages? I tried running apt-get through ssh and it seemed to be downloading at about 50kB/s.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Puppy Linux if you're looking for a lighter Linux distribution.

http://puppylinux.org/wikka/MinimumSystemRequirements

http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm